# Leak_DefinitelyLost warning when creating new node in linked list (C)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list, valgrind, singly-linked-list

I have a program in which I use a linked list, and I have a function called NewNode that is called via main or other functions (even recursive functions).

The program is very slow so I checked it with Valgrind and it seems like everything is working fine apart from this function, as I get Leak_DefinitelyLost error on the malloc, leaking like 1000 bytes (so it must be solved). I suppose I need to free in some way the nodes but I do not really understand how.

Here's how the node is defined and how the function is defined:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
    char* data;
    struct node* next;
}list;

struct node* NewNode(char* to_insert) {
    struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
    new->data = malloc(strlen(to_insert) + 1);
    strcpy(new->data, to_insert);
    new->next = NULL;
    return new;
}
```

EDIT: I have two functions to free, one to free all the list, one to delete only a specific node from the list, here they are:

```
void Free_All(struct node* head){
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    Free_All(head->next);
    free(head->data);
    free(head);
}

struct node* Delete_node(struct node* head, char* to_delete){
    struct node *p, *dummy;
    p = head;

    if (p != NULL && strcmp(p->data,to_delete) == 0) {
        head = p->next;
        return head;
    }
    while (p)
    {
        dummy = p->next;
        if (dummy != NULL){
            if (strcmp(dummy->data, to_delete) == 0){
                dummy = p->next;
                p->next = dummy->next;
                //free(dummy);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (p->next == NULL){
            break;
        }
        p = p->next;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Note: if I try to uncomment the free I get a SIGSEGV error and the program breaks.

Comment: `p != NULL && p->data == to_delete` `==` does not compare strings.

Comment: @0___________ oh you are right, changed in the edit and in the program, still the same error on valgrind, still thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the shown function Delete_node produces a memory leak because the deleted node is not freed with the stored string.

```
struct node* Delete_node(struct node* head, char* to_delete){
    struct node *p, *dummy;
    p = head;

    if (p != NULL && p->data == to_delete) {
        head = p->next;
        return head;
    }
    //...
```

Pay attention to that it seems instead of this comparison

```
p->data == to_delete
```

you have to use standard function strcmp

```
if ( p != NULL && strcmp( p->data, to_delete ) == 0 ) {
```

Using your approach the function can look the following way

```
struct node* Delete_node(struct node* head, const char* to_delete)
{
    if ( head != NULL )
    {
        if ( strcmp( head->data, to_delete ) == 0 ) 
        {
            struct node *tmp = head;
            head = tmp->next;
            free( tmp->data );
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            struct node *p = head;
            while ( p->next != NULL && strcmp( p->next->data, to_delete ) != 0 )
            {
                p = p->next;
            }

            if ( p->next != NULL )
            {
                struct node *tmp = p->next;
                p->next = tmp->next;
                free( tmp->data );
                free( tmp );
            }
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: How should i modify it? 
I tried with free(p) but does not work and gives me SIGSEGV error, i'm clueless

Comment: @cheeroke_69 In the shown code snippet you need to write head = p->next; free( p->data ); free( p ); return head; The same approach use for the deleted point dummy. free( dummy->data ); free( dummy );

Comment: I tried using your code and i still get the SIGSEGV error

Comment: @cheeroke_69 It means that other your code that you did not show has bugs.

Comment: @cheeroke_69 You should close this question selecting the best answer and ask a new question where you will provide a minimal program that reproduces the problem with updates shown in my answer.